# How to get the latest date inserted from the table with Linq to entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

how to retrieve the latestdate inspected from a column

In our app a user can inspect an item and when it inspected the current date is entered into the table. For the same item someother can uninspect it this time nothing is inserted into the table.
       Another user can inspect it and current date is inserted
I need to get the LatestDate Inserted..how to get this with Linq

Let say table name is Statuses  and col name is LastdateInspected

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var query = db.Statuses
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastDateInspected)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

That will return `null` if there are no entries, or the value with the latest `LastDateInspected` value otherwise (i.e. the first result, having ordered by the last date inspected latest-first).

That will get you the whole record, of course. If you only want the date, you can select the `LastDateInspected` column.

Comment: is this gets the last inserted record

Comment: @user1016740: It gets the record with the latest value for `LastDateInspected`. If that's not what you're interested in, you need to clarify your question. Some sample data (and what you'd want returned) would help.

Comment: it worked...and how can i get the no. of days between retrieved lastdateInspected and DateTime.Now..lastdateinspected is of type DateTimeOffset?

Comment: @user1016740: You can use `(DateTimeOffset.Now - status.LastDateInspected).TotalDays`.

Comment: @user1016740: Are you sure you spelled it correctly, with the right capitalization? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx

Comment: select  (DateTimeOffset.Now-Status.LastDateInspected).TotalDays;  i can see the intellisense for TotalDays..but gives the error

Comment: @user1016740: I wouldn't do it in the query - I'd do it within your .NET code *after* the query. There's no need to depend on a SQL translation of that when you can do it easily in-process.