# Get only latest insert row From Foreign table using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code to get data from a DB

```
 result = Context.APP_AuthorityHasamaForm.Where(x =>
                x.UpdateTypeId == (int) UpdateType.Unit && x.AuthorityNum == authorityUnit.AuthorityNum &&
                x.InsertDate >= authorityUnit.FromDate && x.HasamaFormStatus == (int) SendType.Meser &&
                (x.APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm.All(s =>
                    s.RoleId != (int) Role.EligibilityWorker1 && s.RoleId != (int) Role.DepartmentManager2 &&
                    s.RoleId != (int) Role.Treasurer3))).ToList();
```

This is work.
Now i'd like to add a filter to it so only the latest insert row in "APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm" would come out.
I have the column "SignatureDate" in that table which indicate the insert date.

I found a similar question here: [Similar qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525470/how-to-get-the-latest-date-inserted-from-the-table-with-linq-to-entities)

Comment: Why the solution provided by Jon Skeet on that question is not valid to you?

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk: Presumably because Jon Skeet's answer _only_ gets the history entry but OP wants the parent entity (APP_AuthorityHasamaForm) **plus** its _latest_ history entry (APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm). That does change the syntax, it's not as simple/elegant as Jon's answer.

Comment: I dont know where and how to place the "OrderByDescending". If i put it at after the "Where" so i get to filter only the parent table and i need to filter the child

Comment: As there have been a few misunderstandings already, and the question's phrasing leaves it a bit hard to spot, OP wants _"every authority and its most recent signature, instead of every authority and all of its signatures"_. Most people so far seem to answer how to get _"the most recent signature"_, which is notably different from getting the combined set of authority+signature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Flater comments I see the point of the question. I really don't kwnot if there is an option to get only a subset of record in entity-framework when recovering the parent record (I think not). However this workaround maybe it's valid to you:

```
result = Context.APP_AuthorityHasamaForm.Where(x =>
                x.UpdateTypeId == (int) UpdateType.Unit && x.AuthorityNum == authorityUnit.AuthorityNum &&
                x.InsertDate >= authorityUnit.FromDate && x.HasamaFormStatus == (int) SendType.Meser &&
                (x.APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm.All(s =>
                    s.RoleId != (int) Role.EligibilityWorker1 && s.RoleId != (int) Role.DepartmentManager2 &&
                    s.RoleId != (int) Role.Treasurer3)))
               .Select(s=> new APP_AuthorityHasamaForm{
                  [Property] = s.[Property] //as many times as needed
                  APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm = new List<APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm> {s.APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm.OrderByDescending(x => x.SignatureDate).FirstOrDefault()}
               })
               .ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by  "[Property] = s.[Property] //as many times as needed"? What do i need to place insted of "Property"?

Comment: Simple all the properties of the object, `UpdateTypeId = s.UpdateTypeId, ...`, and so on. Intellisense will help you,